# How do I print my datePicker value in my UITextField

Tags: ios, swift, datepicker

Here is my code, I dont want any button to trigger the label. I want it to change every time the picker is moved :

```
    @IBOutlet weak var dateLabel: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet weak var datePicker: UIDatePicker!

    let datePickerView:UIDatePicker = UIDatePicker()

    datePickerView.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerMode.date

    datePickerView.addTarget(self, action: datePickerValueChanged(sender: UIDatePicker), for: UIControlEvents.valueChanged)


func datePickerValueChanged(sender:UIDatePicker) {

    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()

    dateFormatter.dateStyle = DateFormatter.Style.short

    dateFormatter.timeStyle = DateFormatter.Style.short

    dateLabel.text = dateFormatter.string(from: sender.date)

}
```

Comment: The code you posted appears to already do what you want. What issue are you having exactly with the code you posted?

Comment: have you set up the delegate?

Comment: it shows an error saying **Cannot convert value of type 'UIDatePicker.Type' to expected argument type 'UIDatePicker'**

Comment: @Russell yes I've added `UIPickerViewDelegate`

Comment: What line shows that error?

Comment: Please [edit] your question with details of the error. Point out the line causing the error and post the complete error. Always include such details when you post a question.

Comment: Wait - you've got 2 date pickers?  One is created through a storyboard outlet, and the other is created programmatically, but never added to the view?  Why do you need `datePickerView` at all?

Comment: @creeperspeak I only have one date picker. Added on the storyboard

Comment: Then what is `datePickerView`?

Comment: You should get rid of `let datePickerView = UIDatePicker()` and change the subsequent lines in your code to `datePicker.datePickerMode...` and `datePicker.addTarget...`.

Comment: Yes, I messed up my code...I've edited it. Now its working.

Comment: @S.Verma I rolled back your last set of changes because it completely changed the meaning of the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace This

```
 datePicker.addTarget(self, action: datePickerValueChanged(sender: UIDatePicker), for: UIControlEvents.valueChanged)
```

With

```
 datePicker.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.datePickerValueChanged), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.valueChanged)
```

Comment: Good catch. I missed that part.

Comment: @S.Verma See the comment below your question by creeperspeak.

Comment: Right! You don't need to create new pickerview. add target on datePicker iboutlet property.